# gdb changing the default answer for questions

Tags: gdb

While debugging, gdb asks me a question with the default answer being [n] (internal problem, should the session be continued). Is there a way to make it answer y by default and skip the question?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution at https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Maintenance-Commands.html